# While outputting the average number, the program rendered segmentation fault 11

Tags: c, scanf

Here are two sets of codes seem no different to each other, but one of them generates warnings and segmentation fault 11.

```
    //the program which turns out alright
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {int a,b,c,d;float f;
     scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);
     d=a+b+c;
     f=(a+b+c)*1.0/3.0;
     printf("%d %.2f\n",d,f);
     return 0;
     }

   //the program that comes along small issues
   //format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
   //After inputting 3 integers, in mac terminal console, it showed: segmentation fault:11
     #include<stdio.h>
    int main(void)
    {
      int a,b,c = 0;
      float average = 0.0f;
      printf("Please enter three integers you wish to calculate their average:");
      scanf("%d %d %d", a,b,c); //从input把数据放到arithmatic counter里面

      average = (float)(a+b+c)/3.0f;

      printf("\nThe average of the three numbers is:%.2f", average);
      return 0;
      }
```

Comment: The `scanf()` call needs to pass address of `a`, `b`, and `c`.   i.e. `scanf("%d %d %d", &a,&b, &c)`    Without the ampersands, the behaviour is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Here are two sets of codes seem no different to each other,*

You need to look **carefully.**

See the `scanf()` statements:

- `scanf("%d %d %d",&a,&b,&c);` is correct
- `scanf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);` is wrong. Your compiler already warned you regarding this.

`scanf()` expects the supplied arguments against `%d` to be pointer to integer - supplying them with `int`s (basically, any other incompatible type against the expected one) is going to invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Segmentation fault is one of the side effects.